# drupal path for multi sites environment

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How to get path to sites DIR like i have sites/www.example.com i need to obtain this path inside a .tpl file of module, i tried drupal_get_path('theme','my_theme') and path_to_theme() but both of them point to the module DIR. any method that i can use to obtain path to my sites/example.com folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [conf_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/conf_path/6) will help you.

The question is, why do you need your sites/[site] directory?

maybe there's something misguided in your .tpl file. the drupal_get_path() should be sufficient.

Comment: sites/[site] is like varying so its bad to hard code it,i need a path to image from my .tpl file which is in sites/[site]/module DIR, but using drupal_get_path i get path to sites/[site]/module/my_module but instead i need it as sites/[site]/themes/my_theme

Comment: i think drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_theme') should work for you. its strange that it gives you a module dir.. maybe you named them the same?

Comment: no no its supposed to return the active theming element by design , so there s no fault in it. and DIRs are different names, that s why i was looking for alternate methods , tried drupal_get_file also but it also pointed to module DIR...